# "div loading" servlet

Tags: java-ee, servlet, rich-faces

Tenho uma tela que tem a função de enviar um arquivo para o servidor via `servlet` mas como esse arquivo pode ser grande, eu precisava por um panel ou uma div com um gif de load.
Estou usando richfaces, ja tentei usar `popupPanel`, `div` e dar `sendRedirect` para outra pagina enquanto executa a servlet mas nada deu certo.
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="templete">
    <ui:include src="templete.xhtml" />
</div>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/produto-web/FileUploadServlet"> 

    <div id="divUpload">
        Selecione um arquivo : <input type="file" style="width: 435px;" id="file" name="file" size="45" />
        <input type="submit" class="Button" value="Enviar Arquivo" />               

        <p style="color: red;" >${messageError}</p>
        <p style="color: Green;" >${messageSucess}</p>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Sugestão: Use o [rich:FileUpload](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=fileUpload&skin=blueSky) e um managed bean para receber os arquivos. Esse componenete já exibe uma barra de status sobre o upload.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly
Tentei usar, tentei mesmo, mas o componente não funciona achei varias pessoas com o mesmo problema, o componente não popula o listener dele, tive que recorrer a esse método.

Comment: Entendi, não quero poluir sua pergunta se sua decisão já está tomada. Dito isso, 99% das vezes o problema com esse componente é falta de bibliotecas ou algum filtro que está interferindo na aplicação (o GlassFish é especialmente problemático -https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-11988). Você pode também utilizar o [fileUpload](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/upload/single.xhtml) do PrimeFaces (o RichFaces e o PrimeFaces não são mutuamente exclusivos)

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly também pensei nisso, só que nessa questão já é o meu chefe que não quer o uso do `Primefaces`

Answer (score 2):

Eu fiz uma adaptação dessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626873/display-jquery-dialog-onsubmit-while-html-form-is-processing) com seu código.

Adicionei um event `onclick` no seu botão que irá exibir o carregando e a `div` do carregando está logo abaixo dos input.

Depois que você receber o arquivo é só redirecionar o request caso o carregando não suma automaticamente depois. ;)

```js
function showLoading() {
     document.getElementById('loading-div-background').style.display = '';
}
```

```css
#loading-div-background{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: #fff;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

#loading-div{
 width: 300px;
 height: 150px;
 background-color: #fff;
 border: 5px solid #1468b3;
 text-align: center;
 color: #202020;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 margin-left: -150px;
 margin-top: -100px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 behavior: url("/css/pie/PIE.htc"); /* HANDLES IE */
}
```

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/produto-web/FileUploadServlet"> 

    <div id="divUpload">
        Selecione um arquivo : <input type="file" style="width: 435px;" id="file" name="file" size="45" />
        <input type="submit" onclick="showLoading();" class="Button" value="Enviar Arquivo" />               

        <p style="color: red;" >${messageError}</p>
        <p style="color: Green;" >${messageSucess}</p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="loading-div-background" style="display: none">
        <div id="loading-div" class="ui-corner-all">
            <br/>
            Carregando...
        </div>
    </div>
    
</form>
```